# How to share stateSetter functions using the useContext hook?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code high up in the component hierarchy:

```
import VisibilityContext from '../visibilityContext';

...

const [showEditModal, setEditModalVisibility] = useState(false);

...

<VisibilityContext.Provider value={{setEditModalVisibility}}>
   <EditModal/>
</VisibilityContext.Provider>
```

And within the EditModal I have this piece of code:

```
import VisibilityContext from '../visibilityContext';

...

const {setEditModalVisibility} = useContext(VisibilityContext);
```

But the function `setEditModalVisibility` is empty when I console it out in the `EditModal` component. If I pass `showEditModal` instead of `setEditModalVisibility`, `useContext` gives me its correct value. I even tried putting `setEditModalVisibility` in the state using another `useState`, and passed it down, in case `useContext` required references to be stored in a state.

I just want components down the tree to be able to call the `setEditModalVisibility` function. And I want to be able to share this function without having to pass it down the tree as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code how you can effectively manage your state using Context.

```js
    import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const VisibilityContext = createContext();

const Provider = props => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const value = { state: { visible }, actions: { setVisible } };
  return (
    <VisibilityContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </VisibilityContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App() {
  const { state, actions } = useContext(VisibilityContext);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => actions.setVisible(!state.visible)}>
        {state.visible ? "ON" : "OFF"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: The mistake turned out to be a typo. In my failing code, the setEditVisibility was spelled wrong within the EditComponent. It worked as expected when I corrected that. Thanks for the help, your approach incorporates the state inside the Provider, which is great for separation of concerns.

Comment: Best of luck  :)